# Mobx store method is not working on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, store, mobx

I'm having a website with different kind of pins. People can click on a pin and then go to the detail page of the pin. I will get the data from the pin with a method from the store based on the parameter id of the URL. When I refresh the page, the pin returns `undefined`.

This the code in my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useObserver } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {useStores} from "../../hooks/index";

const Pin = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { pinStore } = useStores();
  const pin = pinStore.getPinById(id);

  return useObserver(() => (
    <>
    <p>{pin.id}</p>
    </>
  ));
};
    
export default Pin;
```

This is the code in my store:

```
import {decorate, observable, action, configure} from 'mobx';
import PinService from "../services/PinService";


configure({
  enforceActions: 'observed'
});

class PinStore {
  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
    this.pinService = new PinService(this.rootStore.firebase);
    this.pins = [];
  }
  getPinById = id => this.pins.find(pin => pin.id === id);
}

decorate (PinStore, {
  pins: observable
});

export default PinStore;
```

When I `console.log` id I get the right id and when I `console.log` pinStore I get the right store. The method just stops working on a page refresh.

Comment: Could it be that when you are navigating to the URL, the asynchronous code that fetches the pins from firebase is complete, but when you refresh the page the pins are not loaded yet?

Comment: @Tholle In my console log I can see the pins inside the store.

Comment: Yes, but you are most likely logging a reference to the store that will be updated in the console even if the store updates after you log it. You could try `console.log(getSnapshot(pinStore));` and see if they are there from the beginning.